# Collapsing lists of lists in R (version 2)

Tags: r

This is similar to a question I asked the other day but involves more detail.  Suppose I have lists like this

```
[[25]][[8]]
[[25]][[8]][[1]]
[1] "0" "1" "0"

[[25]][[8]][[2]]
[1] "1" "0" "0"

[[25]][[8]][[3]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"

[[25]][[8]][[4]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"

[[25]][[8]][[5]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"


[[25]][[9]]
[[25]][[9]][[1]]
[1] "1" "0" "0"

[[25]][[9]][[2]]
[1] "1" "0" "0"

[[25]][[9]][[3]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"

[[25]][[9]][[4]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"

[[25]][[9]][[5]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"
```

and I want to collapse these into a list that looks like this

```
[[25]]
[[25]][[1]]
[1] "0" "1" "0"

[[25]][[2]]
[1] "1" "0" "0"

[[25]][[3]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"

[[25]][[4]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"

[[25]][[5]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"


[[26]]
[[26]][[1]]
[1] "1" "0" "0"

[[26]][[2]]
[1] "1" "0" "0"

[[26]][[3]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"

[[26]][[4]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"

[[26]][[5]]
[1] "0" "0" "0"
```

How would I got about doing this?  I know for the other problem I used some form of lapply and unlist with recursive = FALSE, and I'm assuming that's what I have to do here.

Comment: Did you try `unlist(yourList, recursive = FALSE)` to see if it does what you want?

Comment: I stand corrected, it DID work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to just peel off one layer of nesting in your list, you use:

```
unlist(yourList, recursive = FALSE)
```

Of course, remember to assign the output to something.

This is already indicated as a possible approach in your *question*.